# how to store SoapObject data to an array?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I'm using .Net Web Service to fetch data from my server in Android using `ksoap2`.
I'm able to fetch data to `SoapObject` using following code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String _SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/getUserDetails";
        private static final String _METHOD_NAME = "getUserDetails";
        private static final String _NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String _URL = "http://sush19.in/myservice/myservice.asmx";
        SoapObject _response;

        public void getUserInfo() {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(_NAMESPACE, _METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            try
            {
                AndroidHttpTransport aht=new AndroidHttpTransport(_URL);
                aht.call(_SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                _response=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                String s1 = (String)_response.getProperty(0);
                String s2 = (String)_response.getProperty(1);
                String s3 = (String)_response.getProperty(2);
                String s4 = (String)_response.getProperty(3);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Oops..."+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get each values by using above `_response.getProperty`and the values what I'm getting is correct
`anyType{anyType=user1; anyType=pswd1; anyType=user2; anyType=pswd2; anyType=user3; anyType=pswd3; anyType=user4; anyType=pswd4; anyType=user5; anyType=pswd5; anyType=user6; anyType=pswd6; }` 
the data what I'm fetching is username and password.
I want to store it in a array for my further operations such as storing it into Sqlite DB. my database table have two column as

```
username    userPassword
```

I want my above data in following format:

```
user1   pswd1
user2   pswd2
user3   pswd3
user4   pswd4
user5   pswd5
user6   pswd6
```

so that is will be easy to find username with their corresponding password. How can I cast `SoapObject` to an `Array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for What I wanted, thanks to `@Basbous` I got some idea from the code you provided..
Finally I solved it by adding following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String _SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/getUserDetails";
        private static final String _METHOD_NAME = "getUserDetails";
        private static final String _NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String _URL = "http://sush19.in/myservice/myservice.asmx";
        SoapObject _response;

        public Boolean getUserInfo() {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(_NAMESPACE, _METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            try
            {
                AndroidHttpTransport aht=new AndroidHttpTransport(_URL);
                aht.call(_SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                _response=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                int propertyCount = _response.getPropertyCount();
                String[][] userDetails = new String[propertyCount/2][2];
                int temp = 0;
                if(propertyCount % 2 != 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < propertyCount/2 ; i++) 
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                        {
                            userDetails[i][j] = (String)_response.getProperty(temp);
                            temp = temp + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Oops..."+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

the list of values which I got from my Server is now stored in 2D Array `userDetails[][]` and I can pass it to any `Activity` and can access it using `for loop` easily.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create a bean class same as your .net server is returning 
step 2: parse the data and create object of that bean class
step 3: add into array 
and do what ever you want to do

Comment: thank you for your response, I'm new to android so I didn't understand what you told, but I've solved it to get my output by using 2D Array.. I've posted my answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
int propertyCount = _response.getPropertyCount();
if(propertyCount % 2 != 0) {
// The response is not even so you have many option remove last count or return error
}
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(int index = 0 ; intdex > propertyCount/2 ; index +=2) 
{
   map.put((String)_response.getProperty(index), (String)_response.getProperty(index + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried your the code you provided above, but I didn't get how to fetch data from `map`, I went through `HashMap`and I found that first string is `Key` where the second is `value`. So I got some idea from your code and I solved it using 2D array.. I've posted my answer.. Thank you...